# Extract text from long string using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What formula should I be using if I would like to extract certain text or date out from the long string? Text to column doesn't work because I have a list of inconsistent data. Using the below example, I would like to extract Female and the Date of Birth.

For example,
{'Name:''John Doe', 'Age:''29', 'Gender:''Female','Date of birth:''1989-09-28', 'Country:'"United Kingdom'}

I have read MID, LENS, RIGHT and LEFT but really not sure how should I do this. Would be really appreciate if someone can help me in this!

Comment: Is using VBA an option, and is the formatting of your example (i.e. inconsistent single and double quotes, and colons within quotes) representative of the actual data?

Comment: Pure Excel is the wrong tool to be using to parse JSON content.  How did this JSON string end up in a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom UDF.

```vb
Public Function getDemographics(inputString As String, retType As Long) As String

    If retType < 0 Or retType > 1 Then
        getDemographics = "Invalid retType!"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim retArr(1)

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "'Gender:''(\w+).*?'Date of birth:''([\d-]+)"
        If .test(inputString) Then
            With .Execute(inputString)(0)
                retArr(0) = .SubMatches(0)
                retArr(1) = .SubMatches(1)
                getDemographics = retArr(retType)
            End With
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

This uses regular expressions. You provide two arguments, `inputString`, which would be the

```
{'Name:''John Doe', 'Age:''29', 'Gender:''Female','Date of birth:''1989-09-28', 'Country:'"United Kingdom'}
```

and the `retType`. `0` is for the gender and `1` is for the DOB.

On your worksheet, you would just call the function like:

```
=getDemographics(A1,1)
```

Which would return:

> 1989-09-28

Answer (score 0):

There is no one function that will do it.  You'll have to use a combination of functions.
Assuming string is in cell A1 the following function will work for gender.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("Gender:",A1)+9,FIND("'",A1,FIND("Gender:",A1)+9)-FIND("'",A1,FIND("Gender:",A1)+8)-1)
```

You need to find the quote before and after the Gender value and then do the mid on it,
Similar can be done for date of birth

Answer (score 0):

The slight difficulty for using LEFT() and RIGHT() is that MALE and FEMALE have a different letter count. So, you need to use a little abstract thinking. To use LEFT() and RIGHT(), you can do the following (assuming information is in cell A1):

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND("',",A1,FIND("Gender",A1))-1),FIND("',",A1,FIND("Gender",A1))-FIND("Gender",A1)-9)
```

This will return "Female", or "Male" depending on what the individual inputs. (The -18 comes from the distance from the beginning of Gender to the beginning of (Fe)Male being used twice).

Similarly, we can do the same for the birthdate. However, since this is a field of constant length, we can use actual numbers.

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND("birth:''",A1)+17),10)
```

Hope this helps!